# Cx_Freeze build is not including python libraries in zip file

Tags: python, build, compilation, cx-freeze, setup.py

I'm in trouble with cx_Freeze 5.0
I'm working on:
Windows 10 LTSB x64
Python 3.4.4 x86
PyQt5
PyWin32 x86

I never had any issue with this process until I reinstall my Windows10 installation... it was working great and now I can't figured it out why it's happening ...

When I Freeze my python app (python setup.py build) script is copying the whole python libraries outside the python34.zip.
The only thing I got inside python34.zip is *.pyc files (only this.. but a lot)

I don't know why it doesnt include python libraries now and didnt find any options/config, it has to include this automatically ...

If someone can help with this.. :)

Note: nothing has changed in my setup.py, simple setup.py file, copied from standard example just including one asset folder (this one is correctly copied.. no issues)

Thanks !

[cx_Freeze build output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8fcE.png)

Comment: Cxfreeze 5 is quite new and alot has changed. Did you use v5 before the reinstall

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem (if it is indeed a problem) after upgrading to cx_Freeze 5.x. I believe it's mentioned in the changelog here: https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes.html

> 23. Added support for storing packages in the file system instead of in
>       the zip file. There are a number of packages that assume that they are
>       found in the file system and if found in a zip file instead produce
>       strange errors. **The default is now to store packages in the file
>       system but a method is available to place packages in the zip file** if
>       they are known to behave properly when placed there. (Issue #73)

(emphasis mine)
That "method" is apparently described in https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe, specifically the `zip_include_packages` and `zip_exclude_packages` options.

I ended up putting the following as a keyword argument to my setup() call, which solved it for me:

```
options = {"build_exe": {"include_msvcr": True, "include_files": dataFiles, "packages": ["lxml", "idna"], "zip_include_packages": "*", "zip_exclude_packages": ""}},
```