# Why does cx_freeze for Python 3 packs a project into 8000+ files whereas cx_freeze for Python 2 packed the same project in 25 files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, cx-freeze

Let's say `numpy_example.py` is:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(a)
```

- With Python 2.7.9, generating an executable from this with cxFreeze 4.3.3, with:

  ```
  "C:\python27\python.exe" "C:\python27\Scripts\cxfreeze" numpy_example.py 
     --target-dir=.\cxfreeze_x64_py2 --base-name=Win32GUI 
     --target-name=test.exe --exclude-modules=Tkinter,scipy,Crypto,_ssl,bz2,_yaml 
     --include-modules=lxml._elementpath
  ```

  gave 25 files (only `.dll`, `.pyd` and `.exe` files) for a total of 71 MB, with no subfolder:

  [image]
- With Python 3.7.6, generating an executable with cxFreeze 6, **with the same command-line command** gives a **total of 8533 files for a total of 374 MB**!

  In particular, there is the `Lib` subfolder containing many libraries unused for this project:

  [image]

  Also, with the Python 2 version, Numpy was packed into 9 `.pyd` files (and nothing else), whereas here in the Python 3 version it's split in many files and subfolders.

**Question: what has changed in `cx_freeze`, resulting in this less efficient packing?**

**And how to get a similar packing with `cx_freeze` for Python 3 than with Python 2?**

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/675

Comment: My workflow here is to have a separate build-environment with only the bare minimum of packages installed that are needed to run the script. This is most probably not a one-size-fit-all solution but a useable workaround in my case.

Comment: how many dependencies does numpy have

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the answer: it's a feature, since `cx_freeze 5.0`: https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes.html#version-5-0-november-2016

> Added support for storing packages in the file system instead of in the zip file. There are a number of packages that assume that they are found in the file system and if found in a zip file instead produce strange errors. The default is now to store packages in the file system but a method is available to place packages in the zip file if they are known to behave properly when placed there. ([Issue #73](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/73))

Linked: [Cx_Freeze build is not including python libraries in zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143569/cx-freeze-build-is-not-including-python-libraries-in-zip-file)

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out in your own answer, this appears to be the desired functionality. There are other packages out there that can compile to a single executable.

I assume you only want to use cxfreeze, if you know which packages your program **doesn't** need, you can simply list all of them with the [`--exclude-modules`](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/script.html#cmdoption-exclude-modules) flag as you have been. You can filter out packages through trial and error by building your application and then renaming the included libraries in the `lib` directory one by one, adding any unnecessary packages to your excludes list. I was able to reduce the numpy example from 3500~ files to ~1000 this way.

You can utilise the [`distutils`](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html) functionality which I found easier when trying to reduce the final package size.

```py
from cx_Freeze
import setup, Executable
import sys

build_exe_options = {
  "excludes": ["tkinter", ...your excludes here...],
  "optimize": 0
}

setup(
  name = "TestProgram",
  version = "0.1",
  description = "MyDescription",
  options = {
    "build_exe": build_exe_options
  },
  executables = [Executable("main.py",
    base = ("Win32GUI"
      if sys.platform == "win32"
      else None))]
)
```

```
py setup.py build
```

Finally, the cxfreeze FAQ has a question about creating a [single file](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables), although that's not what you're after, it states to use [`IExpress`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress) to create a self-extracting archive (or 7zip), which might be useful to you if package size is the main concern.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please note that I *don't want* to create a single file executable, I just wanted to reduce, if possible, from 8000+ files to something more like 25 files in the case of Python 2.

Comment: I thought so but I added that in there for anyone else who is looking for that from cxfreeze :-)